# get_node: Node not found: "Game/SceneWrapper/Players/Health Potion128/MultiplayerSynchronizer" (relative to "/root")

Tags: networking, godot, gdscript, godot4

When I'm running the server it runs well and spawns all items and doing all rpc calls, but when I'm trying to connect from the client side I'm getting the same error in the client side and this on server side ERROR: Condition "!sync || !sync->get_replication_config_ptr() || !_has_authority(sync)" is true. Continuing. at: _send_sync (modules/multiplayer/scene_replication_interface.cpp:812)

I've tried to change rpc calls from authority to any_peer, but got the same error